# Pumping lemma for context-sensitive language?

Tags: grammar, pumping-lemma, context-sensitive-grammar

i have googled on pumping lemma for context sensitive, and it seems to only produce results for context-free language.

Pumping lemma only allows to prove a language is context free only? and not context sensitive?

Any idea how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are **two** Pumping Lemmas. Pumping Lemma for regular languages allows to prove that a language is **not** regular. Pumping Lemma for context-free languages allows to prove that a language is **not** context-free and hence not regular.

There are no other Pumping Lemmas. To prove that language is context sensitive you could first using Pumping Lemma prove that it is not context-free. Then you must supply a context sensitive grammar that actually generates given language.

Comment: -1 I wouldn't say that there are no other pumping lemmas.  There are similar "iteration lemmas" for LL(k) languages, and even for CFLs there are other lemmas you can use (Ogden's lemma, for example).    Moreover, to prove that something is a CSL, you do *not* need to disprove that it is context-free; any CFL is also a CSL.  On top of that, you can't always use the pumping lemma for CFLs to prove that a language is not CFL.  Finally, you can also prove that something is a CSL by providing an LBA, not just a CSG.

Comment: @templatetypedef "Pumping Lemma" was meant literally. "Similar" approaches are everywhere. Normally you would like to prove that the language is **exactly** CSL. And of course there are many other possibilities, and **exactly** because of that I've written "you **could**".

Answer (score 4):

Pumping lemmas exist for regular, context-free, tree-adjoining, and multiple-context-free languages.  There is a good survey in Johan Behrenfeld's master's thesis:

http://www.flov.gu.se/digitalAssets/1302/1302983_behrenfeldt-johan-alinguists.pdf

There is no pumping lemma for context-sensitive languages. Indeed, this class has considerably more generative power, and include languages without any kind of "pumping" property, e.g. {a^p | p prime}.

Each pumping lemma states a property that is true of a language in that class. It can be used to prove that a language is *not* in that class, as a proof by contradiction.  It cannot be used to prove that a language *is* in that class.

Answer (score 2):

The "pumping lemma-like" approach for tree-adjoining languages actually *is* named the "pumping lemma for tree-adjoining languages" everywhere in the literature. It makes it possible to prove that a language is *not* tree-adjoining, and therefore *not* mildly context-sensitive. Maybe this is the one you had in mind?

It was defined by Vijay-Shanker in [his PhD thesis,](http://repository.upenn.edu/dissertations/AAI8804974/) which is unfortunately not available online. It is nonetheless easy to find how it works by searching the web. Many courses, for instance [this one from the University of Tübingen,](http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/emmy/gf/slides/210507-tag-parsing.pdf) give a good account.